# sharepoint 2013 top navigation menu with sitecollections

Tags: sharepoint, sitecollection

I have a SharePoint Site called ProxymGroup which has multiple affiliates and departments.
I created the webApplication and added 2 **`managed Paths`** of type **`WildCard`** called `Affiliates` and `Departments`.

Under affiliates i needed to create 3 site collections and under departments 2 other SiteCollections. So, here i have the links for the siteCollections:

`http://MyHostName/affiliates/SiteCol1 ...` and `http://MyHostName/departments/SiteCol1 ...` etc.

My goal is to display all that hierarchy in the`TopNavigationBar` menu of the siteCollection because when i activated `SharePoint server publishing` feature and checked `Show SubSites` in navigation tab under `site sittings` it only showed me the subsites, not the siteCollections created under this site.

How can i do please to get that hierachy shown in my `TopNavigationBar` menu???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know there is no ootb way to show information in the navigation shared among site collections. each site has its own master page and can only display subsites, not other site collections.

alternatively, you can create a powershell script that sets the same navigational items for all the existing site collections, adding links for all the existing sites in all menus of all sites

...or just create subsites

Comment: can you help more to write this powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site settings -> Look and Feel -> Navigation and you can add links manually and change the hierarchy as you want  , Please check below image for same.
[image]

Comment: Is there any PowerShell script to do this? or just how to powershell this?